# how to update data into table using in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to update data into table if the record exits if not then create a new record.

```
if(!empty($request->meta_title)){
    $meta = new \stdclass();
    $meta = VendorMeta::firstOrNew(['vendor_id' => $id]);
    $meta->meta_title = $data['meta_title'];
    $meta->meta_desc = $data['meta_desc'];
    $meta->meta_keyword = $data['meta_keyword'];
    $meta->save();    
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 445:vendor_id
```

Comment: First check meta_title available in your table and then decide..

Answer (score 2):

You should define which model attributes you want to make [mass assignable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment), so in your `VendorMeta` class add following code:

```
protected $fillable = ['vendor_id'];
```

Comment: If you find this answer correct, then mark this as accepted answer as it motivates me to answer more questions like this :D , and help others to get appropriate answers quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `$fillable` property on your model.

Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) under Mass Assignment.

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['meta_title', 'meta_desc', 'meta_keyword'];
```